# Show virtual keyboard on smart tv

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera, sony, smart-tv

I develop app on Sony Internet TV (Opera TV OS) and I can't show virtual keyboard when textbox focused.

I use `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.preventDefault();` in my keydown code. 
Can I show virtual keyboard when textbox active ?